# Ansible with Cisco ASA access issues

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use the ASA module for Ansible and I'm having difficulty with connecting to the device.

"Normal" manual ssh works fine for the "admin" user to the ASA device.

I constantly get this error `Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied`

Looking at the `-vvv` output I can see that ansible is passing `PasswordAuthentication=no` when executing the task.

`<192.168.1.64> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/896d0497f8 192.168.1.64 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''`

However I'm not able to find the place in the module where this can be changed. Any advices?

This is **my play**:

```
---
- hosts: 192.168.1.64
  any_errors_fatal: True
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: admin

  vars:
    cli:
      host: asav_lab
      username: admin
      password: "{{asa_admin_password}}"
      transport: cli
      authorize: yes
      auth_pass: "{{asa_admin_password}}"

  tasks:
    - asa_command:
        commands:
          - show version
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
```

The verbose output:

```
TASK [asa_command] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /var/lib/awx/projects/platforms-ansible/asa_test_play.yaml:41
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/network/asa/asa_command.py
<192.168.1.64> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<192.168.1.64> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/896d0497f8 192.168.1.64 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.1.64> (255, '', 'ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.64 port 22: Connection refused\r\n')
fatal: [192.168.1.64]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.64 port 22: Connection refused\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the module (play) on localhost, not on the Cisco device.

<sup>Of course, use `connection: local`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Connection local will not resolve this issue. There are really no good articles or videos showing how to troubleshoot this specific issue. Ansible requires SSH-keys by default, so keeping the default connection type requires that you copy your public key to whatever user you're trying to connect as to the remote device. Log into your Cisco device, enable public key authentication, and copy your public key to the device. If that does not solve your issue, I highly recommend switching to Python scripts, using Paramiko. It's a very well developed library that allows you do send commands remotely and you can backup your configurations as well:

http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html

Comment: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.64 port 22: Connection refused` means : the SSH server is not listening ! Changing for another toolkit seems completely overkill in that situation :-)

Comment: I understand why you might think that, but the OP states in his post: "Normal" manual ssh works fine for the "admin" user to the ASA device." Therefore the device is listening and the exception that was raised is wrong. Its more trouble to continue troubleshooting to use Ansible, when this clearly is not a good use case for the software. Moreover, creating a Python script to use Paramiko for network device managements requires exactly 8 lines of code. I hardly believe that to be overkill.

Comment: agreed to your point (Although most of the time in real situations, we can't change user existing systems in order to fix them).